# MVC (5) Populate a dropdown based on another

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I know I can make a dropdown with a list of `SelectedListItem>` and `@Html.DropDownList("someID")` and os on..

**My question is**, what if you had 2 dropdowns, and the second dropdown depended on the selected item from the first dropdown?

How do you populate it? With JS? How would you go about it? 
Would you change the populate with another list, change the whole dropdown or maybe have a partialview for each dropdown combination, so it's a matter of replacing with the right dropdown.

Comment: here is the basic idea.. On change of the first dropown trigger a Jquery function that does a AJAX call to the server , fetches the records based on the selected value and builds the second dropdown. So when ever there is a change in the first dropdown the process repeats..

Comment: Thanks sounds good. "builds the second dropdown", do you mean a basic javascript loop, populating the new dropdown or some sort of using a HTML Helper?

Comment: @radbyx as the page is already loaded, you can't use the `Html` helper class in that view. So using js/jquery or a partial view is the only way.

Comment: You can return a partial view with just the Option tags back to the Ajax call. And in your ajax success you need to append it to your respective `<select>` tag.. Or if you do not want to return partial view you can return JSON and then loop the values and generate a `<option>` tag and append it to the dropdown

Comment: *`some sort of using a HTML Helper?`* yes this is possible too.. but you need to take the route of returning partial view back (with just this generated dropdown html) and replace your second dropdown completely with this new one.

Comment: Something like this, for manual populate with JS I guess: 
 $("#Countries").change(function() {  
            $.getJSON("/Home/States/List/" + $("#Countries > option:selected").attr("value"), function(data) {  
                var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";  
                $.each(data, function(i, state) {  
                    items += "<option value=""+state.Value+"">" + state.Text + "</option>";  
                });  
                $("#States").html(items);  
            });  
        });

Comment: Thats exactly what you need..

Comment: Thanks man. Feel free to convert to an answer if you like

Comment: :) I am good ... anyways there are lot of similar answers here anyways.. Happy coding brother..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have added NetFiddle example. Works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LikaoX)

I would suggest to use jquery `$.getJson()` to fill second dropdown without refresh to page. You can implement like following example.

**//html**

```
<select id="EventId" name="eventId">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
</select>

<label>Second</label>
<select id="SecondDropdown">  
</select>
```

**// jquery**

```
$("#EventId").on("change", function(){
    showValue($(this).val());
})

function showValue(val)
{
    console.log(val);               
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDropdownList", "Home")' + "?value=" + val, function (result) {                       
            $("#SecondDropdown").html(""); // makes select null before filling process
            var data = result.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#SecondDropdown").append("<option>"+ data[i] +"</option>")
            }

    })    
}
```

**//controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDropdownList(int? value)
{
    List<string> yourdata = new List<string>();

    if(value == 2)
    {
        yourdata.Add("option2a");
        yourdata.Add("option2b");
        yourdata.Add("option2c");
        return Json(new { data = yourdata}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { data = ""}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }           

}
```

Comment: Works like a champ bro

Comment: I am very glad to hear that :)

Comment: i find it really interesting that a lot of silly answers get more upvotes than this one... whatever, @hsnbl your approach is marvelous....

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib thanks for your compliment :)