# disable custom date based on selected Dropdownlist value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to disable custom date and time from the Calendar based on selected Dropdownlist value

Tabel1 : Uername

Tabel2 : Timefrom - Timeto

```
Dropdownlist1 = //show Username from Tabel1 (Done)
Editor= //show calendar (disable date and time or Highlight it  which is equal Timefrom and Timeto in Tabel2 for the same Uername )
```

I need help

```
@Html.DropDownList1("Userlist", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Schedules.TimeTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Controller

```
ViewBag.Userlist = new SelectList(dbContext.Users, "Id", "UserName");
ViewBag.Date= new SelectList(data.FuelersSchedules, "Id", "Timefrom");
```

I want CalendarEditor to disable date and time or Highlight it which is equal Timefrom and Timeto in Tabel2 for user selected in DropDownList1

Comment: this question is not clear to me at all as it currently is - please edit the question to clearly describe your issue, what you've tried, ALL code involved and the expected outcome

Comment: From the title, it kind of sounds like you want to populate one dropdown based on the selection in the first. But your description seems to ask something different.  Please clarify and as GregH asks, provide all the code you have tried so far.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know whether I understood correctly, but have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847579/mvc-5-populate-a-dropdown-based-on-another