# Spring MVC: Populate a dropdown based on another

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

this enum is define in one of my class

```
public enum Type {
        TEXT(1), BINARY(2);

        private final int type;

        AttributeType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Dropdown menu #1

```
<label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label"
    style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #666666">
    <span style="color: red;">*</span>&nbsp;Type
</label>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <form:select class="form-control"
        style="width: 80%" path="">
        <form:option value="" selected="true" disabled="true"
            label="Select a type" />
        <c:forEach var="attribute" items="${Type}">                                                                 
            <form:option value="${attribute}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
    <form:label class="error" id="errorStatus" path=""
        style="color: red;">${errorStatus}</form:label>
</div>
```

Dropdown menu #2

```
<label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label"
    style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #666666">
    <span style="color: red;">*</span>&nbsp;Constraint
</label>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <form:select class="form-control" style="width: 80%" path="">
        <form:option value="" selected="true" disabled="true"
            label="Select a Constrait" />
            <c:forEach var="type" items="${Type}">
                <c:if test="{type== TEXT}">
                    <form:option value="" label="test1" />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="{type== BINARY}">
                    <form:option value="" label="test2" />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        
    </form:select>
    <form:label class="error" id="errorConstraint" path=""
        style="color: red;">${errorStatus}</form:label>
</div>
```

In my Controller class, I have add the list to my attribute ***model.addAttribute("TypeValue", Arrays.asList(Type.values()));***

**What I am trying to do:**

Drop down menu #2 to display test1 if user have selected TEXT in Drop down menu #1 and
display test2 if user selected BINARY in Drop down menu #1

**Actual result**

Nothing is being display after selecting either options in drop down menu #1

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
var diction = {
  TEXT: ["B1", "B2", "B3"],
  BINARY: ["B4", "B5", "B6"]
}

// bind change event handler
$('#EventId').change(function() {
  // get the second dropdown
  $('#SecondDropdown').html(
      // get array by the selected value
      diction[this.value]
      // iterate  and generate options
      .map(function(v) {
        // generate options with the array element
        return $('<option/>', {
          value: v,
          text: v
        })
      })
    )
    // trigger change event to generate second select tag initially
}).change()
```

and I remove all the <c:if test> tag. This solution is base on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847579/mvc-5-populate-a-dropdown-based-on-another).

I am open to ways to improve my code too